# PHP registerNodeClass and reusing variable names

Tags: php, dom

When registering a new base node type with [registerNodeClass](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.registernodeclass.php): it looks like if I re-use variable names for created elements, then custom properties  revert to their default value. I'm actually trying to do this in a loop, but here's an example that I think shows clearly what I mean:

```
<?php

class myDOMElement extends DOMElement
{
    public $myProp = 'Some default';
}

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'myDOMElement');

$node = $doc->createElement('a');
$node->myProp = 'A';
$doc->appendChild($node);

# This seems to alter node A in $doc, not what I expected:
$node = $doc->createElement('b');
$node->myProp = 'B';
$doc->appendChild($node);

# Note: $nodeC instead of $node, this works fine. 
$nodeC = $doc->createElement('c');
$nodeC->myProp = 'C';
$doc->appendChild($nodeC);

foreach ($doc->childNodes as $n) {
    echo 'Tag ', $n->tagName, ' myProp:', PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($n->myProp);
}
```

Why do I get `"Some default"` for tag `a` instead of the value `"A"`?

```
Tag a myProp:
string(12) "Some default"
Tag b myProp:
string(1) "B"
Tag c myProp:
string(1) "C"
```

Comment: This question may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5473967

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume we work with PHP7(the described behavior is peculiar to PHP versions 5..7, at least).

The [`DOMNode::appendChild`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.6/ext/dom/node.c#L1216) method sets up internal structures of the new `DOMNode` object, updates internal structures of the parent node(in our case it's a `DOMDocument` object), then creates and returns a new `DOMNode` object based on the prepared internal structures. Actually the returned object and the appended child node object are the same:

```php
$ret_node = $doc->appendChild($node);
debug_zval_dump($node);
debug_zval_dump($ret_node);
var_dump(spl_object_hash($node));
var_dump(spl_object_hash($ret_node));
```

*Output:*

```
object(myDOMElement)#2 (18) refcount(3){
..
object(myDOMElement)#2 (18) refcount(3){
...
string(32) "00000000121277ac00000000658254f1"
string(32) "00000000121277ac00000000658254f1"
```

The `DOMNode::$childNodes` property read handler creates `DOMNodeList` iterator object. The current iterator value [is fetched](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.6/ext/dom/dom_iterators.c#L149) from a `zval` prepared by [`php_dom_iterator_move_forward`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.6/ext/dom/dom_iterators.c#L175). The latter only a ["creates new object"](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.6/ext/dom/dom_iterators.c#L241)(particularly, `DOMNode`)
based on the internal XML structures.

But the way `php_dom_create_object` creates the objects is tricky! If the object is constructed first time, it saves the pointer by means of [`php_libxml_increment_node_ptr`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.6/ext/libxml/libxml.c#L1193):

```
php_libxml_increment_node_ptr((php_libxml_node_object *)intern, obj, (void *)intern);
```

Next time it calls `php_dom_create_object` it [detects the saved pointer, increments reference count, and returns the previously created object](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.6/ext/dom/php_dom.c#L1202):

```c
if ((intern = (dom_object *) php_dom_object_get_data((void *) obj))) {
  GC_REFCOUNT(&intern->std)++;
  ZVAL_OBJ(return_value, &intern->std);
  return 1;
}
```

In the free-object handler(which is called when the object is being destroyed) the DOM extension [calls](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.6/ext/dom/php_dom.c#L1048) [`php_libxml_decrement_node_ptr`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.6/ext/libxml/libxml.c#L1225).

As we can see, **the DOM objects actually leave as long as any PHP variable. If the variable goes out of scope, it is destroyed. In this case the DOM extension will generate a new object for us.**

Now let's add a destructor to the `myDOMElement` class:

```php
class myDOMElement extends DOMElement
{
    public $myProp = 'Some default';

    public function __destruct() {
      echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Then the following code will show that the `DOMNode` object is being destroyed at the line where we assign `$doc->createElement('b')` to it:

```
$node = $doc->createElement('a');
$node->myProp = 'A';
$doc->appendChild($node);

echo "Marker B-1\n";
$node = $doc->createElement('b');
echo "Marker B-2\n";
$node->myProp = 'B';
$doc->appendChild($node);
```

*Output*:

```
Marker B-1
myDOMElement::__destruct
Marker B-2
```

Since the DOM extension itself doesn't store the `zval` objects, the previous object stored in the `$node` variable goes out of scope and destroyed automatically. From now on we have no references to the PHP object. It's `myProp` property is also destroyed. However, the DOM extension will generate *new instance* for the `a` node, if we request it in a loop:

```
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $n) {
  var_dump($n->tagName);
}
```

Thus, the answer to your question

> Why do I get "Some default" for tag a instead of the value "A"?

is: the object with `$myProp = "A"` is actually destroyed, because it goes out of scope when you assign another object to the `$node` variable, and the DOM extension doesn't store PHP objects for us - it delegates this responsibility to the user. However, the node is still present in the internal DOM structure. Therefore, when it comes to the `A` tag in the loop, the DOM extension generates new object with default properties.

Here is a workaround:

```
foreach (['a', 'b'] as $name) {
  $nodes[] = $node = $doc->createElement($name);
  $node->myProp = $name;
  $doc->appendChild($node);
}
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $n) {
  echo 'Tag ', $n->tagName, ' myProp:'; var_dump($n->myProp);
}
unset($nodes);
```

*Output*

```
Tag a myProp:string(1) "a"
Tag b myProp:string(1) "b"
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks very much for all the detail. I created a PHP bug for this issue: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71872